# Using knockout validation to ensure values in an array are unique

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

My html code:

```html
<button  data-bind="click: addmyEvent">
Add New Event</button><p />
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: myevents">
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
<button  data-bind="click: $root.addProperty">Add Property</button><p />
<div data-bind="foreach: properties">
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
<button data-bind='click: addOptionValue'>Add Option </button>
        <div data-bind="foreach: optionvalues">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: optionvalue" />
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($root), null, 2)"></pre>
```

My javascript code:

```
function myEvent(data){
    var self = this
    self.name=ko.observable(data.name);
    self.properties = ko.observableArray(data.propertydetails);
}

 function Property(data) {
     var self = this
     self.name=ko.observable(data.name);
     self.optionvalues = ko.observableArray(data.optionvalue);
     self.addOptionValue = function (properties) {
         properties.optionvalues.push({ optionvalue: "" });
     }
 }
 var myViewModel = function () {
      var self = this
            self.myevents = ko.observableArray([]);  

    self.addmyEvent = function () {
        self.myevents.push(new myEvent({name:"", properties: ko.observableArray() }));
    }
    self.addProperty = function (ev) {
        ev.properties.push(new Property({name:"", optionvalues: ko.observableArray()}));
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o6juohxL/9/   [1](https://jsfiddle.net/o6juohxL/9/)

I would like to use knockout validation and ensure..

- a) `name` field in `viewmodel.myevents` array is unique
- b) `name` field in `viewmodel.myevents[].properties` array is unique
- c) `optionvalue` field in `viewmodel.myevents[].properties[].optionvalues` array is unique

I found `isUnique` rule amongst user contributed rules [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules) but am unable to figure out how to use the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isUnique` contribution you found should work for your use case. I'll try to explain how the validator works, so you can implement it for all your use cases.

The basics for `ko.validation`:

1. First, you'll have to make sure the `ko.validation` script is loaded and extended with the custom rule.
2. Extend your observable that needs validation using `.extend( /* options */ )`

Now, we can have a look at the `isUnique` implementation. In the documentation you can see that you need to provide either an array/`ko.observableArray` or `Object` with an `array` property. Let's keep it simple and go with the first one.

```
function myEvent(data) {
  var self = this;
  var eventNames = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.name = ko.observable(data.name).extend({
    required: true,
    isUnique: eventNames
  });
};
```

If you'd place a breakpoint in the custom rule, you'll be able to check if the rule correctly runs. But it will use an empty array to check for uniques. Let's fix that.

A `myEvent` instance doesn't know anything about the other events' names. The set of events lives in `myViewModel`. Also, it's an observable array of objects rather than event names. We'll make a new `computed` variable to create an array of event names, and we'll pass a reference on to our `myEvent` constructors:

```
// Create a computed array of names
var myEventNames = ko.computed(function() {
  return self.myevents().map(function(event) { return event.name(); });
});

// When creating a new event, give it access to this array
self.addmyEvent = function() {
  self.myevents.push(new myEvent({
    name: "",
    properties: ko.observableArray()
  }, myEventNames));
};
```

Now, we can go back to `myEvent` and remove the `eventNames` declaration from the constructor. It is now a parameter that is passed by `myViewModel`.

```
function myEvent(data, eventNames) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name).extend({
    required: true,
    isUnique: eventNames
  });

  // Other code ...
};
```

Does this enable you to figure out the other implementations by yourself? Let me know what you think.

Here's a fiddle with the example I gave: https://jsfiddle.net/ute3uem6/

**Edit: if you don't want to litter your view model with computeds, you can use the `predicate` functionality in the `isUnique` rule:**

This is how it works: if you provide a method that tells `isUnique` *how* to compare the current value to the values in an array, you do not need to map the `myevents` observable to an array of strings. It does the same thing, but uses a different approach. I guess it's personal preference which way you choose.

```
isUnique: {
    array: events,
    predicate: function(currentEvent, currentValue) {
      return currentEvent.name() === currentValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: tx, sincerely appreciate it, will check

Comment: could u please provide a fiddle for the predicate functionality, tx

Comment: You pass `self.myevents` instead of `myEventNames` and change the parameter name to `events`: https://jsfiddle.net/yrjdkLym/

Comment: what is happening here--self.myevents.push(new myEvent({
      name: "",
      properties: ko.observableArray()
    }, self.myevents)); what does self.myevents do as an additional field to new myEvent

Comment: `myEvent` needs to validate if its `name` is unique. In order to do so, it needs to "know" the names of all other events. By passing it as an argument to the `myEvent` constructor, it is available to use in the `isUnique` extension of `name`.

Comment: knockout validation documentation says that once you create a custom rule you need to register it, but your code is working without registration code, any idea on this

Comment: I do register it, at the top of the script: `ko.validation.rules['isUnique'] = { /* ... */  }`

Comment: @user3297291 I have a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67374276/required-field-validation-is-not-firing-for-fields-added-into-array validation error is not showing up in array. I tried everything but seems like I am missing something, any help is greatly appreciated