# Required Field Validation error not displaying for fields added into Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, observable, knockout-validation

I am trying to add the fields in the form through `Observable Array` in the `KnockoutJS` to repeat the same section of fields. But the issue is the `Required Field Validation errors` are not displaying for the fields that are added through the `Observable Array`.

Below is what I am trying

```
 var orfViewModel = function () {
 var self = this;
 self.currentPage = ko.observable(1);
 self.referringPage = ko.observable();
 self.StrainDetails = ko.observableArray();

 self.koArrayErrors = ko.validation.group(self.StrainDetails(), {
    deep: true,
    live: true  });

 self.addStrain = function () {
    self.StrainDetails.push(new StrainVM());
 }

  self.remove = function (item) {
    self.StrainDetails.remove(item);
  };
```

I added the `self.koArrayErrors` validation errors within the array. So when a next button on page is clicked I am expecting to see the field required error message on the required fields.
Below is the `next button` logic

```
  self.next = function () {
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
    console.log(self.errors().length);
    if (self.errors().length != 0) {
        self.errors.showAllMessages();
        self.koArrayErrors.showAllMessages();
       
    }
    if (!formIsValid('Page_' + self.currentPage())) {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        return false;
    }

    if (self.referringPage() != null) {
        self.currentPage(self.referringPage());
        self.referringPage(null);
    } else {
        self.currentPage(self.currentPage() + 1);
    }
    self.gotoPage();
};

self.gotoPage = function () {
    $("div[id^='Page_']").hide();
    $("div[id^='Page_" + this.currentPage() + "']").show();
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    self.errors.showAllMessages(false);
    self.koArrayErrors.showAllMessages(false);
};
```

Below is the `StrainVM()` which pushes the data in to the `Observable array` like

```
function StrainVM() { var self = this;

self.pdtNeeded = ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: "Required! Please sect Pdt Needed" } });
 
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

Even though I don't enter anything for `pdtNeeded` field, clicking on the Next button does not take me to next page and does not show the error `Required! Please sect Pdt Needed` next to field.

Users will not know what is not letting them to hit the next page.

How can I handle the validation here that is added to `Observable array`?

Comment: Can anyone please help with what I am missing, am kind of stuck with this

Comment: You mention a couple of things: (1) the validation is not working (2) the validation message is not showing. Both of those can't be true? It would be useful to see your HTML, too. Can you make a JSFiddle or similar that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @sifriday The Validation works , in the sense it doesnot let me go to the next page until I fill in all the required fields but it doesnt show the vlaidation message next to the fields that are required.I never tried fiddle before, and alos new to KnockoutJS, I tried to put the HTML and viewmodel in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DVTrx/1en47mku/34/ any help is greatly appreciated. I m stuck with this for past two days

Comment: I forked your fiddle and added KO and ko-validation as resources so that it can run: https://jsfiddle.net/dpzowjrx/ However, it has bugs (see the browser console). You could use that as a basis to work your code up into something that runs and reproduces your problem? See also http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5424/ for a good example of a ko-validation fiddle.

Comment: I've made a quick edit to clarify the problem as (2) rather than (1) - does that make sense to you?

Comment: @sifriday Thanks  for the example.. The Validation in my form works as given in the example  for the fields that are not added/pushed to the array. The issue is within the fields in the Array.

Comment: @sifriday I am not able to get the working code in the fiddle, I dont have errors in my solution. It is just when the next button is clicked after I added couple of items in to the array with leaving some required fields blank it will not go the next page until I will fill in all the required fields but just not showing the validation message. So the Validation works but not showing up the message.. I appreciate all your help,..

Comment: We're still a bit short of info to understand your problem :-( One thing I cannot work out, where's the HTML that renders self.StrainDetails? If you cannot get a fiddle working, is your app available anywhere?